# EF 6.0.2 Split Table Identity Column Unable to Load all relational objects

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following:

Mapping:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreCopy>().Property(p => p.CostCentreId).HasColumnName("ID_COST_CENTRE").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreCopy>().HasRequired(e => e.Address).WithRequiredDependent(a => a.CostCentreCopy);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreAddress>().HasRequired(e => e.CostCentreCopy).WithRequiredPrincipal(a => a.Address);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreAddress>().Property(p => p.CostCentreId).HasColumnName("ID_COST_CENTRE").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreAddress>().Property(p => p.Address1).HasColumnName("TX_ADDRESS_1").IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreAddress>().Property(p => p.Address2).HasColumnName("TX_ADDRESS_2").IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreAddress>().Property(p => p.City).HasColumnName("TX_CITY").IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreAddress>().Property(p => p.State).HasColumnName("TX_STATE").IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreAddress>().Property(p => p.Country).HasColumnName("TX_COUNTRY").IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreAddress>().Property(p => p.Postcode).HasColumnName("TX_POST_CODE").IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreAddress>().ToTable("MIC_COST_CENTRE_COPY");
    modelBuilder.Entity<CostCentreCopy>().ToTable("MIC_COST_CENTRE_COPY");
```

Model:

```
public  class CostCentreCopy
    {
        [Key]
        public int CostCentreId { get; set; }


        public virtual CostCentreAddress Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class CostCentreAddress
    {
        [Key]
        public int CostCentreId { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }

        public virtual CostCentreCopy CostCentreCopy { get; set; }
    }
```

With this I am able to save all the CostCentreCopy with Address details.
However when I get CostCentreCopy by Id I only get the CostCentreCopy and not the Address.

The table is a flat table with an Identity column.

Is there a way to Create , Return, Update and Delete using EF using table split on a table that has the primary key as an identity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define virtual in you relation ship

```
public virtual CostCentreAddress Address { get; set; }
```

it is evaluated as candidate for lazy loading, so you can explicitly say .Include(c c=>Address) or remove virtual keyword.

If this helps dont forgot to mark it as answer :)

Comment: Even with virtual removed it still does not load.

Comment: can you try using Include?

Comment: Include works, the problem is cascade on delete will not as the relationship is on the same key.